# Submit HTML form in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, electron

is there a way how to submit a form in Electron? I already have HTML form done, but the problem is that, when I tried to send a PHP action file, it comes out as a bunch of PHP text code. as I understand Electron DOES NOT support PHP at all, and I'm trying to create a form, so is there a way how I can submit a HTML form in electron?

Comment: You've got a nodejs environment, so why would you need to submit to PHP? From your description it sounds like your form submission is working correctly and that you just don't have a PHP server.

Comment: Please paste the code that you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1) Upload your HTML and PHP pages on a server, local (like XAMP) or remote (webserver). Then make electron app load this URL and even PHP will work.

2) Don't use PHP or other server side languages. Use Javascript and the nodeJS functionalities